# Warning (Code 1265): Data truncated for column 'sex' at row

Tags: mysql, sql

Warning (Code 1265): Data truncated for column 'sex' at row

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `sex` enum('male','female','unknown') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'unknown',
```

A row will say either one of those above ('male', 'female')

This happens for around 25 million rows out of 40 million . I didn't have warnings on and was importing a database for 2 days just to notice that more than half of it was missing. :(

Can someone please help me with this please?
Thank you very much!

ADDED (redacted some info):
Line that is NOT being imported

```
(3237,'FNAME','LNAME','NNAME','EMAIL@hotmail.com','validated',1,'b9a6638f0c08747549947ce791f8ad5c','female','men',1,'1974-01-03',31799,44680420,-63552470,'B2Y 1X6','CA',1,'6333',647490,'2007-09-15 14:55:13','2010-07-10 21:35:15','2020-01-11 01:44:38',NULL,'2020-01-12 16:43:42',0,170,7,6,0,NULL,2,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,9223372036853944320,0,4,9,1,2,1,NULL,NULL,0,268,0,NULL)
```

Line that IS being imported

```
(2399793,'FNAME','LNAME','NNAME','EMAIL@hotmail.com','validated',1,'410f8a63d579077ef845462a03b7fe8e','male','women',1,'1971-10-04',9,49168230,-121946030,'V2P 1S8','CA',0,'47ae9ac3497446.92557283',152899,'2008-02-10 06:33:39','2013-01-22 19:08:55','2010-10-12 09:36:05',NULL,'2013-01-22 19:08:55',0,175,7,2,4,NULL,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,9223372036853878784,NULL,0,1,1,1,1,NULL,NULL,0,800,NULL,NULL)
```

Comment: So you are trying to import values other than 'male','female','unknown' ?

Comment: What's wrong with `NULL` for unknown?

Comment: hi @P.Salmon no only male, female

Comment: Backtrack a bit what are you importing from and how are you importing? AND please add the target table definition.

Comment: @P.Salmon hi here is the https://pastebin.com/rug7WnKG table. and Im importing using SOURCE db.sql on ubuntu mysql. Im going to try importing again maybe it was just an error on my side because I did put my computer to sleep briefly but I never had this happen from sleep before. Ill try again. Thank you if you find something please let me know!

Comment: Issue not reproduced. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e33bfbbd94fbd41a0eae458f3cebea87).

Comment: @Akina yep :/. Im trying again but yeah I imported around 40million lines and only 14mil were actually in when I checked. Skipped around the following: 1-200k, and then 300k-17mil, and finally 30mil-40mil. Very strange but im going at it again.